# Movie featuring a scene where kids are boiled in a golden pot

Tags: identify-this-movie

I only remember the last part of the movie and some of its plot.

There is a family that has eleven (I'm not sure) kids. Each kid has a particular ability and specialty. Some of the specialties I remember are:

- One of them is a martial arts expert
- One of the girls has the ability to let out infinite tears
- One of the boys is very tall

In the last scene that I remember, the bad guy captures all the kids except the martial arts expert. The bad guy trapped the kids in the Golden Pot and plans to boil them in order to "extract" their power.

This movie is Asian. I don't remember the year of production of the movie. I guess it's 90-2000's. It's translated to my native language. The original langugae perhaps is Chinese or Japanese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sure the movie you're talking about is one of the versions of "Ten Brothers"

The one in [THIS LINK](https://youtu.be/QSctww0Kxng?t=4505) (1995) by director Lee Lik-Chi shows every detail you mentioned
[image]

"The story has been adapted many times in Asian movies and TV series most notably in China and Hong Kong."

See description in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Brothers) and [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=Ten+Brothers+&s=all/)

Greetings from Venezuela!